# D3.js absolute line chart height

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, height, scale

I am creating line charts in D3, but depending on the data I end up with slightly different heights for the charts. I am using

d3.scaleLinear().range([0, 500])

and

d3.axisLeft(500).ticks (6)

I would expect the chart height (500) always to be the same no matter what data it gets, but that doesn't seem to be the case. Is there a way to make sure the height stays constant? [See screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHIjB.gif)

Comment: Please include a minimal reproducable example. In this case particularly, some data that illustrates the problem would be helpful.

Comment: What is this 500 here: `d3.axisLeft(500)`? You have to pass a *scale* to the axis generator.

Comment: Hi Gerardo, yes you are right, I am actually passing a scale to axisLeft which is dynamic according to the data. Not just "500", sorry about the confusion. My code is nested within a larger project, I will try and extract to create an example as soon as I get a chance, thank you for the replies.